# Flatten array structure in Doctrine QueryBuilder JOIN query in Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4, doctrine-query

I have the following custom query in my `PersonRepository` in my Symfony 3 application. It joins the `Person` entity with the `Log` entity where I can grab the created time of the `Person`.

```
public function findAllPlayers()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('p');

    $qb
        ->select('p AS playerInfo', 'al.time AS createdTime')
        ->from('AppBundle:Player', 'p')
        ->join('AppBundle:Log', 'al', Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('al.player', 'p.id'))
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq('p.type', ':type'),
                $qb->expr()->eq('al.type', ':al_type')
            )
        )
        ->setParameter('type', 'midfielder')
        ->setParameter('al_type', 'log.player.created');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

When I feed this through to my Twig template i'm left with this awkward `index` which i'd like to eliminate if possible.

```
{% for index, player in players %}
     <tr>
         <td>{{ player.playerInfo.playerShortname }}</td>                     
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way I can "flatten", for want of a better word, the structure to remove the superfluous `index` from the returned structure. It works, but it's a bit messy and the `index` is not needed or used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking solution for rendering multiple users:-**

You can use the following snippet. It is not mandatory to use index in the for loop. You can refer the first example available in https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

```
{% for player in players %}
     <tr>
         <td>{{ player.playerInfo.playerShortname }}</td>                     
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**If you are looking for a solution to render just one result:-**

There is a method - "getOneOrNullResult". But, it throws an exception if the no. of rows are more than one. So, apply limit = 1 in the DQL and use the method "getOneOrNullResult" instead of "getResult"

To limit the no. of limits, you can use the method - "setMaxResults()"

Your method would like below

```
public function findAllPlayers()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('p');

    $qb
        ->select('p AS playerInfo', 'al.time AS createdTime')
        ->from('AppBundle:Player', 'p')
        ->join('AppBundle:Log', 'al', Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('al.player', 'p.id'))
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq('p.type', ':type'),
                $qb->expr()->eq('al.type', ':al_type')
            )
        )
        ->setParameter('type', 'midfielder')
        ->setParameter('al_type', 'log.player.created');

    return $qb->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

**Note:-**
But, I don't feel joining log to get the created_time is a ideal solution since that can cause serious performance issues as the log table grows. It is ideal to store the created_time in the table if there is a business around it.

Answer (score 0):

Your twig template doesn't use `index` variable so you can feel free to remove it:

```
{% for player in players %}
     <tr>
         <td>{{ player.playerInfo.playerShortname }}</td>                     
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```